# Why aren't the Template tasks coming in when I create a project using a graph extension / C# code?

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization where I'm creating projects in code using the ProjectEntry graph and
the PMProject DAC:

```
//create the project graph...
ProjectEntry projentry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();

pmproj = new PMProject();

//Set the ProjectID:
pmproj.ContractCD = "000001"; //Project preferences is set to allow manually created project CDs...

//The template ID...
var tmplt = (PMProject)PXSelect<PMProject, 
                       Where<PMProject.contractCD, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractCD>>>>.Select(Base, "00TEMPLATE01");

pmproj.TemplateID = tmplt.ContractID;

//The description....
pmproj.Description = "Test description";

//Now save the new project...
pmproj = projentry.Project.Insert(pmproj);                                
projentry.Persist();
```

It's not picking up the template tasks.  Is there something else I need to do to get those tasks to come into the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate method that you need to trigger to populate settings from a project template.
DefaultFromTemplate(Project.Current, newTempleteID, DefaultFromTemplateSettings.Default);

It is executed automatically when you do that from UI, but if you do that from cod you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative approach to the sequence in which the values are entered in the Cache:

```
ProjectEntry projentry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();    
pmproj = new PMProject();
pmproj.ContractCD = "000001";
pmproj = projentry.Project.Insert(pmproj); 

var tmplt = (PMProject)PXSelect<PMProject, 
                       Where<PMProject.contractCD, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractCD>>>>.Select(Base, "00TEMPLATE01");    
pmproj.TemplateID = tmplt.ContractID;
projentry.Project.Update(pmproj);                                        
pmproj.Description = "Test description";
projentry.Project.Update(pmproj);                                        
projentry.Actions.PressSave();
```

Comment: Sorry, Fernando - that didn't work.  Thanks for the help.